# asp FPDF -display text with different character encoding eg.chinese/hebrew/thai

Tags: pdf, asp-classic, fpdf

I am using FPDF library for ASP.I am trying to add Chinese font to it, but its not displaying correct characters. I wrote / copied PHP code and converted to ASP style. Its adding the font file but does not display correct characters. It works for Russian/German but not for Chinese/Hebrew/Thai.

```vb
Set pdf=CreateJsObject("FPDF")
pdf.CreatePDF()
pdf.SetPath("fpdf/")
pdf.LoadExtension "chinese" 
pdf.AddBig5Font "", ""
pdf.SetFont "Big5","",20
pdf.Open()
pdf.AddPage()
'big 5 Text
pdf.write 10,"§Ú¯à§]¤U¬Á¼þ¦Ó¤£¨­Ê^"
pdf.Close()
pdf.Output()
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Hi!
Really old post, but still working.
I've to update a script to support Russian, but difficult to find documentation on this old project
I see you are using a chinese extension to handle not cp1252 encoding.
May I ask you where you have found or if you still have somethere?
It could be very helpful for my project
thanks for your time
Jan